# How can i measure precision with this example?

Tags: information-retrieval, precision-recall

How can I calculated precision . I have the total `corpus` contains `4000 different sentences`. If I did semantic search and got `4 sentences are relevant` and `one is not relevant`  which  `k=5`. How can I measure it precision here ? i'm so confused and hope get help

the `corpus` contains `4000 sentences` and there `20 sentences talked about the food.`
My query is searching for `"Sam eat the food "` and `k=5` gave me the top score using cosine similarity
`4 sentences semantically right` and there is `one is false`

[image]

here does p1 means k =1 , p2 means k =2 ?
so if this is right . will k=1 means that the search for the first sentence has zero result? and for k = 2 , the percentage is 31  ? and so on ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precision comes in two ways.
Overall precision is the ratio of relevant results among all the search results returned.
Precision@k is the ratio of relevant results among the top-k search results returned.

Therefore your precision@5 will be:

precision@5 = relevant_results_at_5 / total_search_results_at_5 = 4/5

Comment: thanks a lot so excuse me does the result for precision depends on the @k ? please can you see the edit post

Comment: It depends on the number of results you obtain and the k you set. Usually, k reflects the number of results the user sees. Suppose you have a ranking function returning 10 documents.
The overall precision will be: number_relevant_doc_returned / 10, 
precision@5 will be: number_relevant_doc_returned_on_first_5_results / 5.

In image, P1=0 means that you do not have any RELEVANT result in the first ranking position. Therefore P1 = 0/1 = 0
Actually precision is a value between 0 and 1 therefore I'm not sure what 31 may mean without more context.